# "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages." when creating a Magento 2 project

Tags: composer-php, magento2

I am following along with [this tutorial](https://digitalstartup.co.uk/t/how-to-install-magento-2-3-and-build-a-web-server/263#chapter3) for installing Magento 2.3 on Ubuntu. I am able to get up to the point where I'm supposed to use composer to create a Magento 2 project using this command:

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition=2.3.0 .
```

After inputting this command, I get the following output:

```
Creating a "magento/project-community-edition=2.3.0" project at "./"
Installing magento/project-community-edition (2.3.0)
  - Installing magento/project-community-edition (2.3.0): Extracting archive
Created project in /var/www/html/.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.0].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 requires magento/composer ~1.4.0 -> satisfiable by magento/composer[1.4.0] from composer repo (https://repo.packagist.org) but magento/composer[1.0.2, ..., 1.6.0] from composer repo (https://repo.magento.com) has higher repository priority. The packages with higher priority do not match your constraint and are therefore not installable. See https://getcomposer.org/repoprio for details and assistance.
```

I have been following the tutorial exactly, however there error does not appear in the tutorial. Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: Please share more details. Are you using Composer v2?  That might be incompatible to Magento 2.3.0 - also, are you sure you want to start a new project on such an outdated version?

Comment: I'm using Composer 2.0.8. I'm trying to install 2.3.0 because that's the version that's being used in the tutorial I'm following.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find in m2 docs that 2.3.0 doesn't support ***composer 2***
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html

So use
`composer self-update --1`

Answer (score 1):

I faced with the same issue.

After changing version of the composer:

```
composer self-update 1.4.0
```

the problem was solved.